# Closing Modal dialog disables input fields

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a function that opens a modal window. First time it opens all input fields are editable. But if the modal window is closed and I try to open it again all input fields are not editable. They are not disabled but I cant focus on them by clicking.

I am suspecting it has something to do with

```
var fns = {
        close: function() {
            opts.returnValue = $dialog.returnValue;
            $dialog = null;
            opts.onClose();
            if (opts.doPostBackAfterCloseCallback) {
                postBackForm(opts.postBackElementId);
            }
            $frame.remove();
        },
        adjustWidth: function() { $frame.css("width", "100%");
        }
    };
```

Below is the full code

```
var $dialog = null;

jQuery.showModalDialog = function(options) {

    var defaultOptns = {
        url: null,
        dialogArguments: null,
        height: ''auto'',
        width: ''auto'',
        resizable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        onClose: function() { },
        returnValue: null,
        doPostBackAfterCloseCallback: false,
        postBackElementId: null
    };

    var fns = {
        close: function() {
            opts.returnValue = $dialog.returnValue;
            $dialog = null;
            opts.onClose();
            if (opts.doPostBackAfterCloseCallback) {
                postBackForm(opts.postBackElementId);
            }
            $frame.remove();
        },
        adjustWidth: function() { $frame.css("width", "100%");
        }
    };

    // build main options before element iteration

    var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptns, options);

    var $frame = $(''<iframe id="iframeDialog" />'');

    if (opts.scrollable)
        $frame.css(''overflow'', ''auto'');

    $frame.css({
        ''top'' : 0,
        ''padding'': 0,
        ''margin'': 0,
        ''padding-bottom'': 0

    });

    var $dialogWindow = $frame.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: opts.width,
        height: opts.height,
        resizable: opts.resizable,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        },
        close: fns.close,
        resizeStop: fns.adjustWidth
    });

    $frame.attr(''src'', opts.url);
    fns.adjustWidth();

    $frame.load(function() {
        if ($dialogWindow) {

            var maxTitleLength = 50;
            var title = $(this).contents().find("title").html();            
            if (title.length > maxTitleLength) {
                title = title.substring(0, maxTitleLength) + ''...'';
            }
            $dialogWindow.dialog(''option'', ''title'', title);
        }
    });

    $dialog = new Object();
    $dialog.dialogArguments = opts.dialogArguments;
    $dialog.dialogWindow = $dialogWindow;
    $dialog.returnValue = null;

}
```

EDIT:

It seems like when I remove the following the problem goes away. But then the elements are not removed from the DOM

```
$frame.remove();
```

**Solved**

This link solved my issue

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9122

I added this prior to removing the dialog:

```
$frame.attr("src", "about:blank");
```

Comment: What is up with the double single quotes instead of single double quotes? You need to change all `''` to `"`

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. I think it was written that way because the javascript is inlined in the html

Answer (score 0):

I have had that type of error before when using modals. In my case, it was caused by errors in my javascript. I took a look at your JS code and found multiple errors with your use of two single quotes(' ') instead of a double quote("). Please change all occurrences of two single quotes in your JS code to one double quote. That should fix your error.

```
    var $dialog = null;

    jQuery.showModalDialog = function(options) {

    var defaultOptns = {
        url: null,
        dialogArguments: null,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        resizable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        onClose: function() { },
        returnValue: null,
        doPostBackAfterCloseCallback: false,
        postBackElementId: null
    };

    var fns = {
        close: function() {
            opts.returnValue = $dialog.returnValue;
            $dialog = null;
            opts.onClose();
            if (opts.doPostBackAfterCloseCallback) {
                postBackForm(opts.postBackElementId);
            }
            $frame.remove();
        },
        adjustWidth: function() { 
            $frame.css("width", "100%");
        }
    };

    // build main options before element iteration

    var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOptns, options);

    var $frame = $("<iframe id='iframeDialog' />");

    if (opts.scrollable)
        $frame.css("overflow", "auto");

    $frame.css({
        "top" : 0,
        "padding": 0,
        "margin": 0,
        "padding-bottom": 0

    });

    var $dialogWindow = $frame.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: opts.width,
        height: opts.height,
        resizable: opts.resizable,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        },
        close: fns.close,
        resizeStop: fns.adjustWidth
    });

    $frame.attr("src", opts.url);
    fns.adjustWidth();

    $frame.load(function() {
        if ($dialogWindow) {

            var maxTitleLength = 50;
            var title = $(this).contents().find("title").html();            
            if (title.length > maxTitleLength) {
                title = title.substring(0, maxTitleLength) + "...";
            }
            $dialogWindow.dialog("option", "title", title);
        }
    });

    $dialog = new Object();
    $dialog.dialogArguments = opts.dialogArguments;
    $dialog.dialogWindow = $dialogWindow;
    $dialog.returnValue = null;

}
```

Comment: I have tried to change all single quotes to double quotes but the problem still persists. The input fields in the second modal window are still uneditable.

Comment: Did you note this line in the above code: var $frame = $("<iframe id='iframeDialog' />");  ? .A double quote was used to encapsulate the single quote used for the id attribute.

Comment: Yes. Changed that too but still has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This link solved my issue....

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9122

I added this prior to removing the dialog:

```
$frame.attr("src", "about:blank");
```